# How to align the bottom edge of multiple TextBlocks with different FontSize

Tags: silverlight, textblock

Here is the XAML sample:

```
<StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" >
    <TextBlock VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Text="Text1" FontSize="20"  />
    <Image VerticalAlignment="Bottom" ... />
    <TextBlock VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Text="Text2" />
</StackPanel>
```

The result is that the textblocks have different bottom-margins depending on their FontSizes, but I need them all to be on one bottom line with no margins. How to get it? In my case I cant use TextBlock + Runs.

Answer (score 0):

Forget several blobks : the bottom position dépends of the font size.
But, in a single paragraph, write the flow of your objects
You should use something like this :

```
     <RichTextBlock>
        <Paragraph>
            <Span FontSize="148">Hello</Span>
            <InlineUIContainer>
                <Image Source="Assets/Logo.png"></Image>
            </InlineUIContainer>
            <Span FontSize="36">again</Span> 
        </Paragraph>
    </RichTextBlock>
```